# Use a $ amount as loss to measure classification performance

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, loss

I'm working on a fraud detection system, and I would like to optimize the system to take account of the cost (in $) of the reviewing department:

I would like to adjust the loss depending on a final cost:

- If a transaction is fraudulent, but the amount is small, it may be more expensive to spend time on a review.
- A non-fraudulent transaction that is reviewed still has a cost.
- Some transaction can be really costly and must be caught

The metric should be the sum of:

- TP --> No cost
- FP --> review cost
- TN --> review cost + the amount of money we got back from the fraud (if it's not the totality)
- FN --> Total amount of the fraudulent transaction

The metric should look like that:

```
def fraudmetric(ytrue, ypred, fraudulentamt, reviewcost):
  cost = [0 if yt==0 and yp==0 else          ## TN
          reviewcost if yt==1 and yp==1 else ## TP
          reviewcost if yt==0 and yp==1 else ## FP
          fa if yt==1 and yp==0 else 0       ## FN
          for yt, yp, fa in zip(ytrue, ypred, fraudulentamt, reviewcost)]
  return np.sum(cost)
```

Is there an elegant way to do that with `Python` ?

Thanks

Comment: Does your code in total work and you want suggestions for improvement or do you encounter an error somewhere?

Comment: I don't think a gridsearch will tolerate that form of metric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily implement a binary table like this using... well, a table. It'd look like this:

```
metric_table = [[0, reviewcost],
                [fa, reviewcost]]
metric_value = metric_table[yt][yp]  # for a given yt, yp
```

I've taken the liberty here to fix what seems to be a bug in your code, since you zipped four iterables and only got three values out. I assume you want the element from `reviewcost` rather than the whole thing. Fix it if that's not correct. Also, I don't see the need to create a temporary array, just to sum it all up, so I've collapsed it to the summation of a generator:

```
def fraudmetric(ytrue, ypred, fraudulentamt, reviewcost):
    return sum([[ 0, rc],
                [fa, rc]][yt][yp]
               for yt, yp, fa, rc in zip(ytrue, ypred, fraudulentamt, reviewcost))
```

Comment: This solution will work, I will pre-populate the cost table. I will just need to create a custom gridsearch to create the different folds for each cross validation.